# Unable to pass xslt variable in the javascript function

Tags: 2010, javascript, xslt

I have added an icon before the image title in asset library. I want to pass the name of the current logged in user and the image title in the JavaScript function to add it in other custom list.

My code for passing the variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageTitle" select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction({$ImageTitle})"> <img src="/add.png" alt="aa" height="10" widht="10"/></a>
```

JavaScript function:

```
         function myfunction(title)
     {
        alert(title);
     }
```

but I am not getting any alert message displaying the title of the image.
What am I missing?

Comment: How does it render? You might have to use `<xsl:attribute />` to output the onclick bit.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to include the <xsl:attribute> in my code as I am beginner in sharepoint development. @JamesLove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're missing quotes. Instead of `myfunction({$ImageTitle})` it should be `myfunction('{$ImageTitle}')`.

Corrected code:

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageTitle" select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('{$ImageTitle}')"> <img src="/add.png" alt="aa" height="10" widht="10"/></a>
```